# Undetermined Coefficients non-homogenous part

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+ 3y'-4y = xe^{-x}+e^{-4x}$$

$$y_p(x)= Axe^{-x} + Be^{-4x}$$

This leads me to a false answer. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks!

Comment: Hint: try finding the homogeneous solution first. Do they overlap with your particular solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the homogeneous part 
$$y''+ 3y'-4y = xe^{-x}+e^{-4x}$$
$$\implies r^2+3r-4=0 \implies (r-1)(r+4)=0 \implies r=1,-4$$
Therefore,
$$y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-4x}$$
for the inhomogenous part try the particular solution 
$$y_p=cxe^{-4x}+(ax+b)e^{-x}$$

Edit

I ended with
$$-8ce^{-4x}+3ce^{-4x}=e^{-4x}$$
$$\implies c=-1/5$$

Your solution for $(A,B)$ is correct
The final solution is

$$\boxed{ y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-4x}-\frac 15xe^{-4x}-\frac 16xe^{-x}-\frac 1{36}e^{-x}}$$

Comment: Nevermind, I missed the minus sign.

Comment: @Isham I found $A = \frac{-1}{6}$ and $B=\frac{-1}{36}$ there is nothing left to find $C$. Could you please verify this situation by calculating it yourself?

Comment: @iyazici I added some lines check it

Comment: @Isham Thanks!. Why did you multiply $e^{-4x}$ with $x$? Is this to find $C$?

Comment: @iyazici  because in the homogeneous solution you already have $e^{-4x }$ so we need a particular solution of the form $$y_p=Cxe^{-4x}$$